# Share image from URL via Twitter app - Android Not Working

Tags: android

```
            case R.id.txtTweetOnTwitter:
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (Utils.checkAppInstalled(getActivity(), "com.twitter.android")) {

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(entryRegistrationAdapter.getList().get(lastPos).entriesImageNameURL));
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
                startActivity(shareIntent);
```

[image]

I pass this as a Uri.parse() but it does not work.

Comment: log your `entryRegistrationAdapter.getList().get(lastPos).entriesImageNameURL)`

Comment: i was already do it. it gives me my url..